# How to retrieve an image from varbinary code?

Tags: sql-server, image

My database is SQL Server. In that one photo data column is there. That is `varbinary` datatype. How to retrieve the original image from that code. Please suggest any better way

Regards,
Pradeep

Comment: This question must have been answered hundreds of times on the web already. It is duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

VarBinary is binary - so cast the field in the resultset to `byte[]`

```
byte[] bytes = (byte[])dataReader["fieldname"];
```

Then use a `MemoryStream` to convert the bytes to `Image`

```
public Image BytesToImage(byte[] bytes)
{
     using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
     {
         Image image = Image.FromStream(ms);
         return image;
     }
}
```